# report viewer doesn't work only for particular report on server

Tags: c#, reportviewerformvc

All report works fine when run on VS,but when i tried after published, i got this error.  this error only comes out in one of the 4 reports(others work fine),in which confuse me even more

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUBAE.png)

i've convert all input to string

input row is

> ```
> row.companyName = company.name;  
> row.companyType = company.companyTypeName;  
> row.companyFields = company.BusinessFields;  
> row.companyAddress = company.companyAddress;  
> row.companyDetail =company.CompanyDetail;  
> row.productGroup= product.ProductGroupName;  
> row.productType= product.ProductTypeName;  
> row.productCode= product.ProductCode;  
> row.orderPrice = Math.Round(order.TotalValue).ToString("#,0.00");  
> row.orderPriceWord =     OrderManager.NumberToWords(Convert.ToInt64(Math.Round(order.TotalValue)));  
> row.fee= order.feeRate.ToString();  
> row.feeWord= OrderManager.NumberToWords(Convert.ToInt64(Math.Round(order.feeRate)));  
> row.age= order.itemAge.ToString();  
> row.ageWord= OrderManager.NumberToWords(order.itemAge);  
> row.feeAmount= Math.Round(order.feeAmount).ToString("#,0.00");  
> row.feeAmountWord= OrderManager.NumberToWords(Convert.ToInt64(Math.Round(order.feeAmount)));  
> row.customerName= aspnet.FullName;  
> row.customerAddress= customer.Address;  
> row.reportDate= DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");  
> row.dueDate= order.dueDate.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");  
> row.yearNow= DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
> ```

Comment: Sounds like a data issue if only happening in 4 of your reports.  The error is saying your value coming from your DB does not match the format or type expected in your class

Comment: tried running locally with setting the connection string to server's sql,report working just fine

Comment: but still not working if running published one

Comment: Interesting, maybe the format of one of your dates is incorrect.   You are publishing to a server? Are your server date setting same as local settings?

Comment: yeah,setting was same

so i tried row.(name) = "test input"; it still result in the same error

Comment: Can you add your class declarations please.

Comment: nvm,found the problem,it was a parse above those codes

pretty much the code is like this

NumberToWordsConverter(Convert.ToInt64(inputstring));

no idea why it's working normally and fails in the server tho